# How to run grafical tool (e.g. deja-dup) as root on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: backup, root, gksudo, ubuntu-17.10

When trying to setup automated backup under Ubuntu 17.10 using Deja-Dup I realized that one can not backup the root directory since a normal user starting the deja-dup application does not have all rights to access all files in /.
(german discussion about rather similar situation can be found here: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wie-sichert-an-mit-deja-dup-ein-systemverzeich/)

The usual workaround to gksu the deja-dup application does no longer work on Ubuntu 17.10. It seams that a decision has been made to prevent users from starting graphical applications as root on purpose for it is often a bad/risky think to do.

However to create regular backups of a Systems / directory with deja-dup the application has to be configured and later on started as root.
Since the typical ideas like gksu, gksudo, sudo -H do not work unter Ubuntu 17.10 I would highly appreciate any advice on a secure practice to get to run deja-dup as root. Can someone help with advice?

Comment: The topic of system backups with dejà dup has known problems, here's the related bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/985512

Answer (score 0):

Grant root access to deja-dup.
`sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/deja-dup`
`sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/deja-dup`
Give permission to it.
`sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/deja-dup`

Please be aware that doing this exposes your system to risk, and it is strongly advised that you change the permissions back to their default settings as soon as you are finished using the backup program.